# Is there a way to control the order of appearance of shipping methods in Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3

If there are multiple shipping methods available for an order, is there way to control the order in which they appear?

The CP doesn't seem to offer a way to re-order them. I'm using something like the following code to retrieve all available methods.

```
{% for handle, method in cart.availableShippingMethods %}
<input type="radio" id="{{ handle }}" name="shippingMethodHandle" value="{{ handle }}" />
<label for="{{ handle }}">{{ method.name }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Craft Pro (3.4.28.1) & Craft Commerce Pro (3.1.12)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any in-built way to do this, no.

A relatively easy hack to achieve it, though, is to loop through your shipping methods (as youare) - but rather than directly outputting them, instead add the data to a twig array (possibly adding some extra data long the way, such as a `sortOrder` of your choosing, based on the handle) - and then use Twig's `sort` to sort your options based on your desired criteria (e.g. the aformentioned `sortOrder` or just by e.g. the price - before then actually outputting those options from the array, rather than the initial direct loop.

It's not awesome/elegant, but it works!